# How to clear these email suggestions from the top of the iOS keyboard?

Tags: ios, keyboard

I have googled a few times but I am unable to get the answer I wanted. Most results are about the Mail app one way or another.

For me, my problem is actually as highlighted in the attached screenshot.

Above the keyboard there are two email suggestions for filling into the input boxes.

How can I remove them without the need to change any contact details?

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, you can only disable the email suggestions in Safari (Settings > Safari > Autofill > Use contact info). It may affect some other apps too.